# How do i store data received from another activity

Tags: android

I have three activities in activity one the user fills in a spinner and in activity two he picks a choice and in activity three he inputs his details. 
How do I store all this data in an external database from activity one to three?

Comment: You should read the basics of saving data in Android http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to store the data, or only pass it from one to the next?

If you need to store it, [SQLite](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html) is one option among many.

If you only need to pass it along from one to the next, [intent extras](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) are probably want you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the values with intent and in activity three you can insert into database

```
intent.putExtra("key_name",value);
```

Refer [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html) tutorial

Answer (score 0):

This is First activity

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(FirstaActivity.java,SecondActivity.class);
intent.putextra("Key",value);
startActivity(intent);
```

In 2nd activity

```
String data= getIntent().getStringExtra("Key");
Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.java,ThirdActivity.class);
intent.putextra("Key",data);
startActivity(intent);
```

In 3rd activity

```
String data1= getIntent().getStringExtra("Key");
store data1 into database.
```

Answer (score 0):

When you insert the data in Spinner,you should use Sqlitedatabase if Data amount is large,otherwise you can use Shared Preference, Now when you use SQLiteDatabase after that you can use Data in Any activity using `openOrCreateDatabase("DB_Name",SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);`
 method of SQLiteDatabase.
Sure this will be easy for you.